# How to create dropdown under a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a dropdown menu that can keep dropping down but instead of going down, dropping to the right like this pic

[image]

I know how to create a dropdown menu that goes below only like this pic
[image]

My current HTML code :

```
<div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Consumer Management</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="tuto2"><a href="#">www.e-homes.com.my</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">hehe</a></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

My current CSS style :

```
.nav li {

  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: left;
  width: 220px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -7px;
 }

.nav a {

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transition: .3s background-color;
 }

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
 }


.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
 }



 @media screen and (min-width: 650px) {

 .nav > ul > li {
   text-align: center;
  }

.nav > ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 0;
  }

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
  }

.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
 }

.nav li ul li {
  display: block;
   }
 }
```

Does anyone know the CCS style to enable it going to the right?

Comment: Try to give CSS positioning for the inner <ul> as absolute to the parent <ul> which is relative. Set the bottom, left, right, top attributes as per your requirement.

Comment: You need to use CSS. Show us what you have tried?

Comment: You can refer this example https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Comment: Thank you all for helping, the link definitely helped @Saniyasyedqureshi

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it like this:

```css
.outer {display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column}
.tutorials > ul, .tuto2 > ul {display: none}
.tutorials:hover > ul, .tuto2:hover > ul {display: inline-block}
```

```html
<ul class="outer">
  <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Consumer Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="tuto2"><a href="#">www.e-homes.com.my</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">hehe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope the below helps.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: thin solid white;
}

li>a {
  color: white;
}

.main>li {
  background-color: blue;
}

.sub>li {
  background-color: red;
}

.subsub>li {
  background-color: green;
}

.sub,
.subsub {
  display: none;
}

.main>li:hover>.sub,
.sub>li:hover>.subsub {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="main">
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Consumer Management</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li class="tuto2"><a href="#">www.e-homes.com.my</a>
          <ul class="subsub">
            <li><a href="#">hehe</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

html code

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

if you have doubt for creatring drop down link you may Refer this link  `https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h`